# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel

I'm editing a Laravel script.
I want add a form option in admin panel
I put this codes:
for route:

```
Route::post('order-check/edit-order', [
'as' => 'admin.orders.details.change',
'uses' => 'OrderStatusController@change',
'middleware' => 'can:admin.orders.index',
 ]);
```

OrderStatusController:

```
public function change(Request $request){
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'state' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    $order = Order::findOrFail($request->id);       
    $order->billing_address_1 = $request->address;
    $order->billing_city = $request->city;
    $order->billing_state = $request->state;
    $order->save();
    return back()
        ->withInput()->withSuccess('OK');  
}
```

And resources file:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.orders.details.change') }}">
<input name="id" value="{{ $order->id }}" hidden>
<input name="address" value="{{$order->address}}">
<input name="city" value="{{$order->city}}">
<input name="state" value="{{ $order->state }}">
<button type="submit">
```

In that resources file, I already compacted the $order variable.
Now when I click on the button,

> The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

error appears
But I have not used from delete method at all

Comment: your question is very confusing ..pls precise..but remove 'middleware' => 'can:admin.orders.index', from route file ..then check

Comment: it not was fixed

Answer (score 0):

you need add  @csrf   between form tag  @csrf

Comment: I have added it, but it not was fixed